# Is there any limitation on number of test methods in the Apex test class?

Tags: apex, eclipse, code-coverage

I wrote 35 test methods in my test class to cover all the scenarios. When i ran the test class from Apex Test Execution code coverage is showing up as 58%.
When i check the coverage in developer console it is showing only few methods.

When i ran the same class through eclipse the coverage is showing up as 98%.

I have cleared the test history but no use.

Comment: DevConsole is buggy.. Cant depend on it. Atleast thats my experience

Comment: The last time I tried to use dev console for testing, I got internal server errors on around 50% of my test classes.  Eclipse (aka the force.com ide) has been the most reliable for me.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to clear your code coverage (yes, I know it's not an answer). The hiccups are kind of explained at the SF blog: http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/11/code-coverage-and-the-force-com-developer-console.html

Comment: There is no limitation, i believe. Once I have written 74 test methods to cover scenarios. So don't worry up to 74 (or more).

Answer (score 2):

No limitation on number of test methods.  Don't rely on the developer console coverage.  It is buggy.  Only use Eclipse when you want to be sure about coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You must rely on what eclipse is showing.Developer console is having some issues these days.

Comment: can you substantiate or illustrate what you are saying?

Comment: Is there any limitation on number of test methods in the Apex test class?

Comment: @Kapil : no there isn't